# Teams Personal app Compatibility: Can we show unsupported message in teams app for ios and android?

Tags: microsoft-teams

In teams personal static apps for compatibility, the app should support below OS or browsers:

Microsoft Windows
macOS
Microsoft Edge
Google Chrome
iOS
Android
But the app we are building don't support the android or IOS versions, can we show graceful failure message in IOS/android or inorder to pass the app submission we should make it working in IOS or android versions too?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the manifest json , so that we can try it from our end?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Microsoft Teams store validation guidelines Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/teams-store-validation-guidelines#tabs),
Tab experiences must be fully responsive on mobile (Android and iOS).

[image]

Please get in touch with teamsubm@microsoft.com if you have any further questions.